# Front End Developer Steps

Tags: reactjs, frontend

as a front end developer. What do you guys usually do first when starting a new project as a front end dev? What are your steps when starting the project? hehehe could use some advice

Answer (score 2):

Take pen and paper and start drawing your ideas.

Collect your ideas first and **think about them for a few days**. After that, **make your goal clear**, and after you have **made new sketches**, think one level deeper: What are the dependencies and requirements? What does my data structure look like?

Create your base and try to **handle all possible states** (loading, error, success, ...). Then there are many other steps...